# Show the problem of a machine visiting infinitely many tape cells on some input is undecidable

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions, undecidability, halting-problem

I am attempting to prove the following problem is undecidable. Given a Turing machine $M$ and input $x$, does $M$ visit infinitely many tape cells on input $x$?

I am considering a reduction from the halting problem. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Does a TM that visits infinitely many tape cells ever halt?

Comment: No, but even if it visits a finite number of cells, it may still not halt.

Comment: hint: consider a machine which after each step shifts the entire contents of the tape one cell to the right.

Comment: To the right, find many similar quesitons. Have a look and improve your question with an approach. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a related meta discussion.

Comment: While it's true that not all TMs that halt visit infinitely many tape cells, the halting problem is solvable if you restrict TMs to those which visit a finite number of cells. A reduction from the Halting problem should work: being able to solve this problem would allow you to solve the Halting problem would allow you to solve the Halting problem for all TMs by first using the algorithm to see whether it visits infinitely many cells; if not, run the algorithm to see whether a TM visiting a finite number of cells halts.

Comment: @Patrick87 How do you solve the halting problem for TMs which visit a finite (not necessarily bounded!) number of cells?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Run the TM. If you ever enter the same configuration (tape contents, head position, state) then your TM is in an infinite loop, so you know that it doesn't halt. If your TM halts before reaching the same configuration, then your TM halts on the input. Every TM which visits a finite number of cells may enter into a finite number of such configurations, and must therefore either halt or repeat a configuration after a number of steps equal to the number of configurations +1, by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: We don't need to know the number of possible configurations; just that for the given TM and input, the number is finite - which follows from our assumption that a finite amount of tape is used. In fact, if $n$ tape cells are used, we have $|\Sigma|^n \times n \times |Q|$ unique configurations.

Comment: @SashoNikolov: Now that Patrick87 has turned his comment into an answer, don't you like to answer too? I'll remove my placeholder CW-answer in this case.

Comment: as noted on previous comments try to figure out how to simulate $M$ on input $x$ with a machine $M'$ that at every step of the simulation converts a blank symbol $\epsilon$ on the right of the tape to an "alternative" blank symbol $\epsilon'$. Then - if you are confident with the previous argument - try to prove the undecidability using another weird approach: build an $M'$ that simulates a (Turing complete) [tag system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_system) that simulates $M$ :-)

Answer (score 3):

Based on my comments, I might as well make this an answer, and let the community decide whether it's right or not.

Suppose you could decide whether a TM visits an infinite number of cells on an input. Here's how to solve the Halting problem given this information:

```
Halts(TM, input)
1. if the TM visits an infinite number of cells for the input then return false
2. configurations = {}
3. while(true)
4.     configurations.add(non-blank tape area, TM head position, state)
5.     let the TM execute one step
6.     if state is halt accept or halt reject, return true
7.     if configurations.contains(non-blank tape area, TM head position, state) then return false
8. loop
```

This works because, if the TM doesn't visit an infinite number of cells, it visits some finite number of cells, $n$. The number of distinct configurations is therefore $|\Sigma|^n \times n \times |Q|$, and `configurations.size()` will never be bigger than this. By the pigeonhole principle, we must satisfy at least condition #7 in a finite number of moves. If none of the reached configurations enters a halting state, we never will; so we have to halt before we see the same configuration twice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this approach is correct. Try to visit a new blank cell between two computation steps by e.g. using some markers.